# Dynamic UI Shiny Implementation

Tags: r, user-interface, dynamic, shiny

I have the following dataframe:

```
a<-rep(c("cat","dog","bird"),each=5)
b<-letters[1:length(a)]
c<-data.frame("pet"=a,"level"=b)
```

I'd like to make a shiny app that has a pull down menu for selecting `pet` and then have a dynamic set of checkboxes that appear beneath that have corresponding values of `level` for checkbox options.

So, selecting `cat` would bring up a checkbox group of `a,b,c,d,e` and then selecting `dog` would change those checkboxes to only show `f,g,h,i,j`, etc.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `updateCheckboxGroupInput` function inside an observer (`?observe` The `observe` function "observe" `input$pet`and and will automatically re-execute when `input$pet` changes, and then update the checkbox group).

For example :

```
a<-rep(c("cat","dog","bird"),each=5)
b<-letters[1:length(a)]
c<-data.frame("pet"=a,"level"=b)

runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Example"),

    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("pet", "Select a pet", choices = levels(c$pet), selected = levels(c$pet)[1]),
      tags$hr(),
      checkboxGroupInput('levels', 'Levels', choices = c$level[c$pet == levels(c$pet)[1]])
    ),

    mainPanel()
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    observe({
      pet <- input$pet

      updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "levels", choices = c$level[c$pet == pet])
    })
  }
))
```